# How can I enhance my SQL Statement using the SUM function?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I am trying to SUM my **UNUSED** column (named UNUSED). The challenging part in this context here is, I have a COUNT function. The results are calculated correctly. But how can I add a SUM function in this statement? Appreciate any kind advice.

Following is this SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(ADMIN_NO)*Courses.PricePerPax AS USED
FROM Student_Prog_Course 
INNER JOIN COURSES ON COURSES.CID=Student_Prog_Course.Course_ID
GROUP BY COURSES.PricePerPax
```

Result:

```
284.94
356.92
1000
5203.6
```

**Expected Result: 6845.46**

**COURSES**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Courses] (
    [CID]              INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PFID]             INT           NOT NULL,
    [Start]            DATE          NULL,
    [EndDate]          DATE          NULL,
    [Title]            VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [PricePerPax]      FLOAT (53)    NULL,
    [Claim]            FLOAT (53)    NULL,
    [NoOfPax]          INT           NULL,
    [Status]           VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Date_Last_Action] DATE          NULL,
    [Exam]             NCHAR (1)     NULL,
    [PreApproved]      NCHAR (1)     NULL,
    [Comments]         VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Provider]         VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [School]           NCHAR (10)    NULL,
    [Remarks]          VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Courses_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([PFID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Programme_Funding] ([PID])
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Courses] ([CID], [PFID], [Start], [EndDate], [Title], [PricePerPax], [Claim], [NoOfPax], [Status], [Date_Last_Action], [Exam], [PreApproved], [Comments], [Provider], [School], [Remarks]) VALUES (200, 4, N'2020-05-03', N'2020-10-03', N'Accounting Analytics', 89.23, 89.23, 29, N'Pending', N'2020-07-08', N'N', N'N', N'', N'NCS', N'SIT       ', N'')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Courses] ([CID], [PFID], [Start], [EndDate], [Title], [PricePerPax], [Claim], [NoOfPax], [Status], [Date_Last_Action], [Exam], [PreApproved], [Comments], [Provider], [School], [Remarks]) VALUES (201, 7, N'2020-05-04', N'2020-10-04', N'Understanding ASP.NET c#', 500, 250, 20, N'Pending', N'2020-07-08', N'Y', N'Y', N'NIL', N'NYP', N'SIT       ', NULL)
```

**STUDENT_PROG_COURSE**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student_Prog_Course] (
[Admin_No]       VARCHAR (7)  NOT NULL,
[Course_ID]      INT          NOT NULL,
[Course_Status]  TEXT         NOT NULL,
[Claim_ID]       INT          NULL,
[Personal_Email] VARCHAR (50) NULL
```

);

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student_Prog_Course] ([Admin_No], [Course_ID], [Course_Status], [Claim_ID], [Personal_Email]) VALUES (N'189097X', 112, N'Completed ', 1, N'AAA@BBB.COM')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student_Prog_Course] ([Admin_No], [Course_ID], [Course_Status], [Claim_ID], [Personal_Email]) VALUES (N'194567C', 112, N'Approved  ', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student_Prog_Course] ([Admin_No], [Course_ID], [Course_Status], [Claim_ID], [Personal_Email]) VALUES (N'190234A', 112, N'Cancelled ', NULL, NULL)
```

Comment: can you add your table schema, a couple of rows of sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: @zaitsman Updated my Q.

Comment: Your schema does not have column called `UNUSED` so what exactly are you trying to SUM?

Comment: I derived the column **UNUSED** from here: COUNT(ADMIN_NO)*Courses.PricePerPax. I want to sum this new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is USED that is required to be summed, what about:

```
SELECT  SUM(USED)
FROM    
(
    SELECT COUNT(ADMIN_NO)*Courses.PricePerPax AS USED
    FROM Student_Prog_Course
    INNER JOIN COURSES ON COURSES.CID=Student_Prog_Course.Course_ID
    GROUP BY COURSES.PricePerPax
) u
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Just curious, if I were to bind this SQL statement to a chart control, which column name should I use?

Comment: You should provide an alias when defining the select (e.g. SELECT SUM(USED) AS SomeName) and then refer to the alias (e.g. SomeName)